# valac command not found on windows

Tags: windows, vala, msys2

I have tried to get vala working on Windows and it does not work, I have followed the steps on the website:

- I downloaded and installed msys2
- Then I ran

  ```
  pacman -Syu
  pacman -Su
  ```
- Then I ran the command on the vala website

  ```
  pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config mingw-w64-x86_64-vala
  ```
- Then I tried to run `valac` and it says `command not found`.

Am I missing something? I tried just `vala` but that does not work, I tried to run the command again and it said that it was already installed and up to date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably did not start "mingw64.exe" (The msys2 subsystem for mingw64-x86_64).

There are three distinct subsystems in msys2 (each also has its own pacman package repository):

- msys2
- mingw32
- mingw64

You can launch a shell for any of them. The current best solution is to use the included launchers (`msys2.exe`, `mingw32.exe` and `mingw64.exe`).

See here for more documentation:

https://www.msys2.org/wiki/Launchers/

https://www.msys2.org/wiki/MSYS2-introduction/